# Displaying score in libgdx game

Tags: java, android, libgdx, 2d-games

So i am having trouble keeping a display of the score in a game i am creating. I was wondering how would i go about doing that? this is what i have so far:

```
package com.catgame.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Music;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Sound;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class CatGame extends ApplicationAdapter implements InputProcessor {
SpriteBatch batch;
Sprite cat;
OrthographicCamera camera;
final float CAT_WIDTH = 0.75f;
final float CAT_HEIGHT = 0.50f;
Sound meow;

int score = 0;
String scorePrint;
BitmapFont scoreFont;


@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    cat = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Cat.png")));
    cat.setSize(CAT_WIDTH,CAT_HEIGHT);
    scoreFont = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("score.fnt"));
    float aspectRatio = (float)Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/
            (float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    scoreFont.getData().setScale(0.5f);


    camera = new OrthographicCamera(CAT_HEIGHT * aspectRatio,
                                    CAT_HEIGHT);
    camera.position.set(CAT_WIDTH/2,CAT_HEIGHT/2,0);

    meow = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("Meow.wav"));

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);

    scorePrint = "Hello";


}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera.update();
    batch.begin();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    //cat.draw(batch);
    scoreFont.draw(batch,scorePrint,camera.position.x,camera.position.y);
    batch.end();
}
```

I have tried scoreFont.draw() method but it doesn't seem to work. not sure why, maybe my positioning is wrong since I have an ortho camera or something. But When i tried to used the draw font, nothing appeared. The red circle in the image below shows where i would want the score around.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9t0fI.png

Answer (score 1):

Draw your font in render method and change your font colour or background colour.It might be possible because you black  background colour match with BitmapFont colour.

Comment: The font is white and the background is black

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw the score (or whatever you want to see on screen) inside the render function, because each render clears the canvas and redraws.

Comment: just updated sorry about that. Right now I got it set up for the center but eventually want to move it over. But even that does not show.

Answer (score 0):

You are drawing the font too big. When you don't specify a scale for the font before drawing it, it draws it at a scale of one font pixel to one world unit. In your case, your camera height is less than one, so you are only seeing a fraction of one pixel of the first letter in your text, which is likely just empty space. Call `setScale` on the font after setting up your camera, using the appropriate scale to get it down to the size you want.

Comment: so i would essentially do what i did with the sprite except setScale in the create function??

Comment: Yep. -------------------

Comment: I just tried this and i still don't see it. Should I just shrink the image and not even use a camera for something like this??? I have update the code above to show what i attempted. Maybe i am not scaling the font right??

Comment: Try also setting `font.setUseIntegerPositions(false);`. But this will make the edges of the letters slightly blurry. Really, fonts are designed to be used pixel perfect (contrary to the proper way to draw everything else). If you are using them in a UI, it is easiest to use a ScreenViewport for your UI camera so you don't have to scale the font. If you have to mix them into your game scene (so they can't have their own camera), then it becomes necessary to scale them and turn off integer positions, but in that case you should use trilinear filtering on the font to minimize blurriness.

Comment: thanks for the help. Now I am trying to setUseIntegerPosition(false) but now its just crashing the app entirely. not sure why @Tenfour04

Comment: nevermind. was setting it in the wrong place. But not that I did that, I still cannot see the text at all. not sure what the heck is going on here with this. Sorry about this but I appreciate the help